# HTML/PHP: How to do date validation before/after submit. Check if selected day is +/-5 days away from current day

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, date

I have a time tracker website where some team members can enter the time they spend daily on different tasks. Normally they should enter the time every day, so they should have access only to the current day.

But just in case they forget to enter the time on some occasions, I have also created a calendar datepicker, where they can select a different date than the current day, so they can go back in time or in the future to add time spent on a different day than the current day.

I would like to restrict this to only 5 days before the current day and 5 days after.

So in the form below the user can select a different date than the current day.
I would like to check if it is +/- 5 days away from the current day, then go to the page where they can enter the time, and if it is more than +/- 5 days then display an error message.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Calendar:</div> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action = "enterTimeDD.php" method = "post" id="calendarID">
                <input type='text' class='datepicker' id='currentDay' name='currentDay' autocomplete='off'>
                <input type='submit' value='Go to' id='greensubmit'>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Which is the best way to achieve such behavior?

Edit 1:
I have found something that might be in the right direction on this page: [Source](https://itnext.io/https-medium-com-joshstudley-form-field-validation-with-html-and-a-little-javascript-1bda6a4a4c8c)

I adjusted the code as follows:

```
            <script>
                const calendarID = document.getElementById('calendarID');
                const currentDay = document.getElementById('currentDay');
                const greensubmit = document.getElementById('greensubmit');

                var minDate=new Date(), maxDate = new Date();

                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()-5); 
                maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()+5);

                if (currentDay > minDate && currentDay < maxDate ){
                    greensubmit.disabled = false;
                }
                else{
                    greensubmit.disabled = true;
                }

                greensubmit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    calendarID.submit();
                });

            </script>
```

But now the submitt button doesn't work even if the date is in the +/-5 day range. Any suggestions?

Edit 2:
I have tried hardcoding a date just to test if the code works.

Comparing `var testDate = new Date("2018-11-01");` with minDate and maxDate I cannot change to any date. And it is correct as the date is outside the +/- 5 range.

Comparing `var testDate = new Date("2018-11-08");` with minDate and maxDate I can change to any date. And it is correct as the date is in the +/- 5 range.

So the piece of code from Edit 1 works.

The problem I see is that `const currentDay = document.getElementById('currentDay');` doesn't get the date that I select with the datepicker in order to compare that to minDate and maxDate.
And I don't understand why. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: you could use AJAX to php, or JS/jQuery

Comment: `var minDate=new Date(), maxDate = new Date(); minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()-4); maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()+5);`

Comment: I think the best way is validate it after and before submit, one time in the frontend and another in the backend. If you search for compare dates or check date range for php and javascript you will find thousands of answers.

Comment: Don't. Someone will find a valid reason to backfill information from _six_ days ago (before a holiday?) and you've written yourself out of that possibility for no good reason.